# .htaccess applies only to root, while I need it to work across the domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following `ReWrite` Rule

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !{developer_ip}
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

This .htaccess should redirect all requests to the `maintenance.php`, except the requests coming from `{developer_ip}` which is my own ip address.

Problem:

The above rules work, but when I click on any of the internal links, it again shows me maintenance.php (which due to the IP rule, must not happen) which ends in either a `index.php?{some_query}` or a URL which is also already rewritten by the .htaccess itself, such as `/Page/About-US` (which originally is `index.php?page_id=200`.

Now I want the `.htaccess` to redirect all requests to maintenace.php (which already is doing) but no the requests coming from `{developer_ip}`. The above rules are fine, except the part excluding my own ip address, which redirects me for the internal links.

Comment: turn on logging and watch what it does

Answer (score 1):

Perform an internal rewrite to maintenance page and keep your rules in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !{developer_ip}
RewriteRule !^maintenance\.php$ /maintenance.php [NC,L]

# skip any requests alredy rewritten to maintenance.php
RewriteRule ^maintenance\.php$ - [NC,L]

# rest of your rewrite rules
```